# Creating complex object using POCO in EF

Tags: poco

I am trying to understand how to create a complex POCO which in the backend tied to a stored procedure or multiple tables. All the examples I have seen are simple one table to one entity or two tables. Could some one point me to a link or example on how to create a complex POCO which talks to stored procedure or multiple table. Or is it just my imagination?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following link and it has some good information, thought share it with anyone interested.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx